# how to install a extension to chrome which is not in the chrome webstore via winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, plugins

I have a chrome extension made for my organization. I don't want to publish it in chrome webstore.. I want to create a installer for it to install directly to chrome.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
I made a c# form that copies the extension to the chrome extensions folder
`C:\Users\ted\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\`

But this don't seem to be working..

Please help.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try this?  https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/

Comment: After the move file you should load this extension via chrome://extensions/

Comment: i moved the extension files to that folder.. but my extension is not showing up in the chrom://extension page :0 @BK52

Comment: just moving the files will not help you!